# Extract driver from PE

Tags: binary-analysis, pe

My exact question sounds like: 
Are there any tools for automated resources extraction such as driver or executable to the ready-to-go `.sys` or `.exe`/`.msi` ?

I googled several ways, but they haven't solved my problem.

- **[Exescope](http://hp.vector.co.jp/authors/VA003525/emysoft.htm#6)** -- spoilt the output binary
- **7zip** -- produced some rubbish(i.e. I can not figure out how to use it to achieve the goal)
- **[Universal Extractor](http://www.legroom.net/software/uniextract)** -- same as 7zip

Any tips will be appreciated.

Comment: http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/

Comment: @Paul, thank you. Output is sufficent for draft disassembly, but a lot of resources in produced file seems to be cropped.

Comment: ResourceHacker reads from the RAT (Resource Address Table). So, any PEs you found that have self extracting PE which doesn't reside in the RAT (Excluding talking about obfuscated PEs) will likely to reside in the .data section. I don't know of any tools to automate searching PEs within .data section. This maybe off topic as it's not automated but you could do it yourself by doing doing signature scan on PE or DOS header. Here's a website for signatures within the PE: http://marcoramilli.blogspot.co.uk/2010/12/windows-pe-header.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is already a ready made tool which scans for embedded PE within another PE. 
Download [**Exeinfo PE**](http://exeinfo.atwebpages.com/) and use the ripper option. It will automatically scan and dump any embedded PE within the master file.

However, obviously, the embedded PE should not be compressed or encrypted in any way.

Answer (score 0):

> pe-carv.py is script can be used to carve out portable executable
> files from a data stream.

http://hooked-on-mnemonics.blogspot.com/2013/01/pe-carvpy.html

> It relies on pefile by Ero Carrera to parse the portable executable
> file format and calculate the file size. Since the script relies on
> the portable executable file format, data that is appended to the end
> of the file (overlay) will not be carved out.
>
> The algorithm of the
> script is simple. Search for the strings of the MZ header in a data
> stream, if found read from the address to the end of the file, then
> pass the buffer to pefile. If no exceptions are thrown by pefile then
> we have a valid portable executable file. If an error occurs, search
> for the next MZ header and then start the process again.